# Python ctypes with Abstract classes

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I want to use C++ classes from Python with the ctypes library:

My C++ Classes:

```
class ClassAInteface 
{
  protected:
  ClassAInterface() {}

public:
 virtual ~ClassAInteface() {}
 virtual void MethodA() = 0;
};

class ConcreteClassA : public  ClassAInteface 
{
public:
 ConcreteClassA();
 virtual ~ConcreteClassA();
 //ClassAInteface Methods
 void MethodA();
};
//Second class which uses the First class
class ClassB 
{
  public:
   ClassB(ClassAInteface* firstClass);
   virtual ~ClassB();
   void MethodB(int param);
}
```

Now i want to use this classes in Python with CTypes:

```
extern "C" {
    ConcreteClassA* ConcreteClassA_new() { return new ConcreteClassA(); }
    void MethodA(ConcreteClassA* classA) { classA->MethodA(); }
    ClassB* ClassB_new(ConcreteClassA* classA) { return new ClassB(classA); }
    void MethodB(ClassB* classB,int param) {dl->MethodB(param); }
}
```

Using the first Class in Python works fine with:
...Importing the shared-library ... --> sharedLib

```
#Create a Python Class
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = sharedLib.ConcreteClassA_new()
    def MethodA(self):
        sharedLib.MethodA(self.obj)
objA = ClassA()
```

But when i want to use the second and the first class together in Pyhton with:

```
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self,firstClass):
        self.obj = sharedLib.ClassB_new(firstClass)
    def Drive(self):
        sharedLib.MethodB(self.obj,angle)
objA = ClassA()
objB = ClassB(objA)
```

I get:

> self.obj = sharedLib.ClassB_new(firstClass) ctypes.ArgumentError:
>   argument 1: : Don't know how to convert
>   parameter 1

I think without an abstract class it would work?
But how can i use my classes in Python easily?

Comment: I'm surprised you can successfully create an instance an abstract `ClassAInteface` since its constructor's `private` and `ConcreteClassA_new()` function isn't declared a `friend` nor is it a derived class. Beside that, you cannot use an abstract class as a function return type so the function shouldn't compile.

Comment: The ConcreteClass_new() function is only a function which creates a ConcreteClass pointer and i is not needed to declare it as friend or a derived class,an good example here: [link](http://bigbang.waterlin.org/bang/using-python-ctypes-to-link-cpp-library/)

Comment: The `ConcreteClassA_new()` function returns a pointer to the dynamically allocated `ConcreteClassA` _instance_ it _creates_ via the `new` operator and the class' default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

How would ctypes know to use the `obj` attribute? Use [`_as_parameter_`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#calling-functions-with-your-own-custom-data-types).

First, make sure you're setting the parameter and result types. ctypes defaults to using a C `int`, which will invalidate 64-bit pointers.

```
sharedLib.ConcreteClassA_new.restype = c_void_p

sharedLib.ClassB_new.restype = c_void_p
sharedLib.ClassB_new.argtypes = [c_void_p]

sharedLib.MethodA.restype = None
sharedLib.MethodA.argtypes = [c_void_p]

sharedLib.MethodB.restype = None
sharedLib.MethodB.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_int]
```

---

```
class ClassA(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._as_parameter_ = sharedLib.ConcreteClassA_new()

    def MethodA(self):
        sharedLib.MethodA(self)
```